# Do all switching converter ICs support multiple topologies?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to design a low-noise power supply for small-signal audio (+/-12-15V, ~1A). As part of this, I'm investigating advanced SMPS topologies like the SEPIC and Ćuk converters. Few controller/converter ICs mention support for these topologies in their datasheets, and the ones that do (such as the [LM5001](http://www.ti.com/product/LM5001)) seem to support a more common topology as well, usually boost. I also found an [EE Times article](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1272382) on how to design a negative buck converter using a boost converter IC, and an [app note](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-1083.pdf) that implements a buck-boost converter using a buck converter IC. What I have not found is a general list of which topologies are supported by each type of controller/converter. Thus, I have two questions:

1. Can all converter ICs be used to implement multiple topologies?
2. If so, which topologies are supported by each type of basic converter IC (buck, boost, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

An SMPS controller<sup>1</sup> IC may support multiple converter topologies.  But a single IC almost never supports all common converter types.

There is a family of converters derived from boost converter: flyback, SEPIC, boost proper.  A controller that can do boost, usually can do the rest of the boost family too.  Usually, one controller can't do both buck family and boost family.

<sup>1</sup>  SMPS *controller IC* drives external power switches.  SMPS *converter IC* has power switches on board.  Converter ICs tend to be less versatile than controllers.

Comment: So the difference in transfer functions doesn't matter?

Comment: Closed loop feedback adjusts to transfer function  ( \$ \frac{1}{1-D} \$ for boost vs. \$ \frac{D}{1-D} \$ for SEPIC ).  Although I suspect that feedback loop compensation (external to the IC) may be different.